# ASP.NET MVC 2 Asynchronous operation and Reverse Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 and .NET framework 3.5. I have a table of data in my view and on a button click, I process all the information in the table row by row on server side. Every row of operation takes some time to complete.

So I thought of updating the view, once every row is processed, like giving the status of every row as pending, in-progress or completed.

I tried by using a Task parallel library to process the long running process and update the session after every row is processed. And then long poll another Action method and retrive the session data periodically. Like shown below.

But I am not able to update the session here.

```
public ActionResult ProcessData()
    {
        ModelData model = HttpContext.Session["ModelData "] as ModelData ;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (Info item in model.DataInfo)
            {
                ProcessRow(item);
                Session["ModelData"] = model;
            }
        });

        return View(model);
    }

 public ActionResult GetLatestModel()
        {
            ModelData model = HttpContext.Session["ModelData"] as ModelData;
            return View(model);
        }

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnSubmit").live("click", function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%= Url.Content( "~/Process/ProcessData" ) %>',
                success: function() {
                    setInterval(UpdateView, 5000);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function UpdateView() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%= Url.Content( "~/Process/GetLatestModel" ) %>'
        });
    }
</script>
```

I am not sure how to proceed on this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "But I am not able to update the session here." What do you mean by "not able to update"? What's your desired behaviour and what's actually happening?

Comment: @millimoose : due to async call, the HttpContext is long gone by the time the task executes. Hence no session.

Comment: Any chance of updating to .net 4.5/mvc4? This sort of problem is ***considerably*** easier to tackle with built in async/await `Task<ActionResult>` controller methods. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: @millimoose : I was trying to update the model, which was stored in a session variable. So, that I can refer it back from a different Action Method.

Comment: @spender : Unfortunately no. Is there any way with MVC 2 and framework 3.5

Comment: I think the easiest way to approach this would be to keep a static MemoryCache ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx ) or other (better suited) collection and to use this instead. Or a database.